# Horizontal scroll when using table responsive with Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I have a table with lots of headers and data, I need to make it responsive

As mentioned in the documentation, I wrapped the  inside a  and gave the div `table-responsive` class.
The issue is that the table takes up a lot of space which alters the parent's width and I'm left with a horizontal scroll on my main page as well as inside the table. (At least table-responsive is working.)

Below is my code where div is a parent element and table is a child element.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tbody> 
    etc...
  </table>
</div>
```

```
<div
          className={`mt-4 w-100 table-responsive ${styles?.tableHeight}`}
        >
          <table className="table w-100">
            <thead className="">
              <tr>
                <th className="gap-2 text-left" style={{ width: "50px" }}>
                  <div className=" fw-700 ps-4">ID</div>
                </th>
                <th
                  className="gap-2 text-center"
                  style={{ width: "120px" }}
                >
                  <div className=" fw-700">Business</div>
                </th>
                <th
                  className="gap-2 text-center"
                  style={{ width: "100px" }}
                >
                  <div className=" fw-700">Owner Name</div>
                </th>
                <th
                  className="gap-2 text-center"
                  style={{ width: "150px" }}
                >
                  <div className=" fw-700">Owner Email</div>
                </th>
                <th
                  className="gap-2 text-center"
                  style={{ width: "120px" }}
                >
                  <div className=" fw-700">Business Email</div>
                </th>
                <th className="gap-2 text-left " style={{ width: "100px" }}>
                  <div className=" fw-700 ms-4">Business Mobile</div>
                </th>
                <th className="gap-2 text-left " style={{ width: "100px" }}>
                  <div className=" fw-700 ms-4">Last update</div>
                </th>
                <th className="gap-2 text-left " style={{ width: "80px" }}>
                  <div className=" fw-700 ms-4">Status</div>
                </th>
                <th className="gap-2 text-left " style={{ width: "100px" }}>
                  <div className=" fw-700 ms-4">Subscription</div>
                </th>
                <th className="gap-2 text-left " style={{ width: "100px" }}>
                  <div className=" fw-700 ms-4">Expiry Date</div>
                </th>
                <th className="gap-2 text-left " style={{ width: "80px" }}>
                  <div className=" fw-700 ms-4">Action</div>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {tableData?.length > 0 &&
                tableData?.map((data, index) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td>{data?.id}</td>
                      <td>{data?.business}</td>
                      <td>{data?.owner}</td>
                      <td>{data?.ownerEmail}</td>
                      <td>{data?.businessEmail}</td>
                      <td>{data?.ownerMobile}</td>
                      <td>{data?.businessMobile}</td>
                      <td>{data?.update}</td>
                      <td>{data?.status}</td>
                      <td>{data?.subscription}</td>
                      <td>{data?.expDate}</td>
                      <td>
                        <div>
                          <button>Edit</button>
                          <button>Delete</button>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Did you gave any custom class to table to increase its width?

Comment: Try giving container class to your parent element, like this- `<div class="container table-responsive"> `

Comment: @NehaSoni yes I have given custom width, code added above
I've also removed all custom styles but the horizontal scroll on the main pg is persistent